# How to restore schema and data-only backups from different databases

Tags: postgresql

I had my application installed in few companies. In one of them (newest, with the smallest database) I made a "major change" in the most of functions (there are about 80 functions) and in trigger functions (about 10 of them). And it worked here, application in this company works on new version and they are fine. But now I want to update app in previous companies and here is the problem: I want to add old data from this company's databases to new db schema. I tried to just backup schema-only from "new" database, data-only from old database and then connect it just by restoring first schema, then data but it failed (A lot of errors with foreign keys/triggers etc). Then I tried to first restore schema, then restore every single one of tables separately. And it was a bit better (All tables works), but my backup didn't restore All of the data. And here is my question:

There is any way to do something like that? Some dump function to backup only functions and trigger functions or something?

Comment: You'll have to come up with a script of DDL and DML statements that transforms the old database schema to the new one and preserves the data.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally get it to work!

First - I restore SCHEMA-ONLY backup like the previous times.

Then I made a new DATA-ONLY backup, but on pgAdmin i checked:

- Do not save owner - Yes,
- Do not save tablespace - Yes,
- Do not save privilege - Yes,
- Do not save unlogged table data - Yes,
- Disable Trigger - Yes,
- Disable $ quoting - Yes

After restoring this data backup to previous restored schema, everything went alright :)